# Magento 2.4.1 Elastic Search critical error failed to create query "all shards failed"

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, elasticsearch

I updated my site to Magento 2.4.1 after that in my exception.log i continueously get folllowing error :

main.CRITICAL: {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"query_shard_exception","reason":"failed to create query: For input string: "10-19-459-1090-1788-1973-2061-2196-2344-2360-2431-2851"","index_uuid":"I3R3qrSMRd2ez0BKKOMduQ","index":"magento2_product_1_v35"}],"type":"search_phase_execution_exception","reason":"all shards failed","phase":"query","grouped":true,"failed_shards":[{"shard":0,"index":"magento2_product_1_v35","node":"NQce1OBCTMKf0HQwsXBjyg","reason":{"type":"query_shard_exception","reason":"failed to create query: For input string: "10-19-459-1090-1788-1973-2061-2196-2344-2360-2431-2851"","index_uuid":"I3R3qrSMRd2ez0BKKOMduQ","index":"magento2_product_1_v35","caused_by":{"type":"number_format_exception","reason":"For input string: "10-19-459-1090-1788-1973-2061-2196-2344-2360-2431-2851""}}}]},"status":400} {"report_id":"3e2c9f4c0d0d1bd840f9c76a0d00a0acd7e1775ed0bc8c69ad0afb32dd14f8f7","exception":"[object] (Elasticsearch\Common\Exceptions\BadRequest400Exception(code: 400): {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"query_shard_exception","reason":"failed to create query: For input string: \"10-19-459-1090-1788-1973-2061-2196-2344-2360-2431-2851\"","index_uuid":"I3R3qrSMRd2ez0BKKOMduQ","index":"magento2_product_1_v35"}],"type":"search_phase_execution_exception","reason":"all shards failed","phase":"query","grouped":true,"failed_shards":[{"shard":0,"index":"magento2_product_1_v35","node":"NQce1OBCTMKf0HQwsXBjyg","reason":{"type":"query_shard_exception","reason":"failed to create query: For input string: \"10-19-459-1090-1788-1973-2061-2196-2344-2360-2431-2851\"","index_uuid":"I3R3qrSMRd2ez0BKKOMduQ","index":"magento2_product_1_v35","caused_by":{"type":"number_format_exception","reason":"For input string: \"10-19-459-1090-1788-1973-2061-2196-2344-2360-2431-2851\""}}}]},"status":400} at /public_html/vendor/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/src/Elasticsearch/Connections/Connection.php:632)"} []

Need help to sort this thing out.

Comment: Check Elasticsearch connection [test connection](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/config-guide/elasticsearch/configure-magento.html).
Thanks

Comment: yes i checked it and its successful in test connection although i faceing same error

Comment: I get the same - struggling to find the solution...